# discard ID from a string in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following variable of type string:

```
[string]$name = "juan maria alonso 78899229N"
```

how can i get only juan maria alonso and discard the number and the letter, there are always 8 numbers and a letter with a regular expression?

result:

```
[string]$name = "juan maria alonso"
```

i try this:

```
 $result = where-object {$name -notmatch '[0-9][a-zA-Z]'};
 echo $name
```

but I receive it empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```ps
$result = $name -replace '\s\d+[A-Za-z]',''
$result
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do what you want. I've taken the liberty to add the ability for a collection of names because it is likely you have more than one, otherwise you would just manually edit the name.

This code does assume the ID code is always at the end of the string.

```
# create collection
$names = ("juan maria alonso 78899229N", "testing 12345678A", "and some more 12345678A")

# iterate through collection
$names | foreach-object {
    # create new variable with the name in this loop and convert to string.
    $name_from = $_.ToString()

    # Get the name by removing the last 10 chars (a space and id code)
    $name = $name_from.Substring(0,$name_from.Length - 10)

    #print $name for reference.
    $name
}
```

Comment: it's not what i'm looking for

Comment: Then what are you looking for? This code does what you want. Be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

This option

```
Clear-Host
[regex]::Matches("juan maria alonso 78899229N",'\b[^\d\W]+\b').Value -join ' '

# or this

Clear-Host
"juan maria alonso 78899229N" -replace '\d+[a-zA-Z]'

# Results
<#
juan maria alonso
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for grins, another option:

```
PS keith> [string]$name = 'juan maria alonso 78899229N'
PS keith> $result = $name -replace '\s\w+$' ### '<space><one or more word characters><end-of-string anchor>
PS keith> $result
juan maria alonso
PS keith> $matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
0                               78899229N
```